# Wamp Error-You don't have permission to access / on this server.Access through IP

Tags: wamp

I want to access my website through IP
I am getting this error-
" Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.
  Apache/2.4.35 (Win64) PHP/7.2.10 Server "
Eg. My IP: xxxx.xxx.xxx.xxx   when i put this ip in browser URL bar some website's index page should open kept in www folder. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem and I solved it.

1. change '**Require local**' to '**Require all granted**' in apache2.4.35 httpd.conf and httpd-vhosts.conf files.
2. restart wampsever.

it works,the point is 'local' means JUST local so You don't have permission to access through IP